# Internet access within Android App - Using phonegap and Eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I have created/published an app to Google Play using the Phonegap framework and Eclipse.  My question most likely has a simple answer, but after some unsuccessful research, I've reached an impasse.  There are a few iframes that are supposed to access SoundCloud mp3 files online.  The sound files are displaying (thus accessing the internet), but they will not play any music, rather once you click the play button, the iframe changes to a generic SoundCloud social media display.  Additionally, there are a few links (target = _blank) that are still displaying within the app view rather than opening a browser window.  This is a lesser issue for me, but I believe these two issues are inter-related, as I haven't really coded anything in Java except the necessary lines in onCreate in the Main Activity.  Again, this app works, it's really just the nuances of debugging the internet access that I can't figure out.  Here are some more salient pieces of information, and I thank you for your advice and feedback:

PhoneGap: Cordova 2.9

Permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use connection object (navigator.connection) to check for Internet connectivity.
Below is the link for further details-
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

If are you accessing it within i-frame you may need to use parent.window.navigator.connection